# Find a binary relation on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $(S,+,*,0,1)$ is a ring. Define a binary relation $R$ on $S$ satisfy
>   1. for $\forall g\in S$ , $gRg$.
>   2. for $\forall a,b\in S$ , if $aRb$ and $bRa$ , then $a=b$.
>   3. for $\forall a,b,c\in S$ , if $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$.
>   4. for $\forall a,b\in S$ , there must hold $aRb$ or $b Ra$.
>   5. for $\forall a,b,c\in S$ , if $aRb$ , then $(a+c)R(b+c)$ and $(a*c)R(b*c)$
>   Prove there is such a binary relation on $\mathbb{R}$. ALSO prove there is not such a binary relation on $\mathbb{C}$.

First I thought the first one is easy. I want to define the binary relation $R$ as "$\le$" on $\mathbb{R}$. It satisfies the first four properties. But sadly it doesn't satisfy if $aRb$ , then  $(a*c)R(b*c)$. How can we construct such a binary relation on $\mathbb{R}$ ? Also how to prove it doesn't exist on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Please check property $3$, it seems to look wrong.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited.

Comment: The last property surely has to be wrong. For example, if $-1 \leq 1$ (without loss of generality), then multiplying by $-1$ gives $1 \leq -1$, giving $1 = -1$. So, the last property must be a mistake.

Comment: The usual version of the last half of 5 requires $0Rc$ and then $\le$ works fine.  Please check the question.  Then to prove it doesn't work in $\Bbb C$ you have either $0Ri$ or $iR0$.  Derive a contradiction from each.

Answer (score 1):

There is a clear mistake in the definition, as from 2, 4 and 5 alone you can prove that for all elements $x,y\in S$, $x=y$.

Proof:

From 4, we have that either $-1R1$ or $1R{-1}$. By the multiplicative property from 5, with $c=-1$ we get the other of the two relations, and then by 2 we get $1=-1$. Thus in particular, we have $1+1=0$

Again, from 4, we have either $0R1$ or $1R0$. From the additive property, using $c=1$ and the result from the previous paragraph, we again get the other of the two relations, and thus by 2 we get $0=1$.

Multiplying by an arbitrary $x$ then gives $0=x$ for all $x$, and thus $x=y$ for all $x$ and $y$. $\square$

---

Depending on the exact definition of “ring” used, the one element ring may or may not exist. If it exists, then the relation as defined in the question exists (it is simply the equality on the one-element ring). Otherwise, no ring can have a relation with those properties. In any case, $\mathbb R$ quite obviously cannot have such a relation, as it has more than one element. Nor can $\mathbb C$.

If property 5 is changed so that the multiplicative property only holds if $0Rc$, then those conditions just describe a total order compatible with the ring structure, and $\le$ qualifies on $\mathbb R$. This is almost certainly what was intended.